# Queued function not executing with dequeue

Tags: c#, queue

Dequeue does not call the queued function, console shows there is 1 action queued.

This code:

```
private static Queue<Action> changeMaterialTask = new Queue<Action>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddAction(() => Test());
    while (changeMaterialTask.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("About to deque");
        changeMaterialTask.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine("I've dequeued");
    }
}

public static void AddAction(Action task)
{
    changeMaterialTask.Enqueue(task);
}

public static void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worked");
}
```

print on console "Worked" when queued function executes at dequeue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Queue<T>.Dequeue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.dequeue?view=netframework-4.8) method returns the item you have dequeued from the queue, in this case an `Action`. You then need to do something with it, for example:

```
var action = changeMaterialTask.Dequeue();
action();
```